# Cannot get [{"foo"}, {"bar"}, {}, {}] |> filter empty to work

Tags: prelude.ls

This works:
`[1 to 10] |> filter (> 4) |> console.log #[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`

This works: 
`empty {} #true`

but this doesn't:

`[{"foo"}, {"bar"}, {}, {}] |> filter empty |> console.log # [ { foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' }, {}, {} ]`

`[{"foo"}, {"bar"}, {}, {}] |> map (-> console.log (empty it) ) #true true true true` 
Is this a problem with empty?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround is to implement my own `empty`:

```
empty = (obj)->
  Object.keys(obj).length is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the appropriate `empty` function for the type of input you are using, in this case, use `Obj.empty`. The `empty` you are using comes from `List.empty`. Using that on an object should probably be an error instead of what currently happens.

```
[{"foo"}, {"bar"}, {}, {}] |> filter Obj.empty
```